# Time Complexity of Array Comparison Method

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have a method that compares one single dimensional array against every row in a two-dimensional array to see if they're equal. Both arrays have the same amount of columns. For example, {1,0} and {{1,0},{1,1}} - I would compare {1,0} to {1,0} and then to {1,1}. If there are n rows in the two dimensional array and m columns in both arrays, what would be the time complexity? Is it O(mn)?

Comment: Every entry in the 1D array against every entry in the 2D array? That would be O(mmn).

Comment: Why two m's? I'm comparing the same column index in both the single and multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Ah. The statement about "every entry" was not clear. You are comparing the row vector (1D array) against each row of the 2D matrix, then? In that case it is O(mn).

Comment: Yes, sorry. I could've been clearer.

Comment: Wait, doesn't the m-dimentional vector comparison cost O(m) time?

Comment: @POPOL Yes, and it is done `n` times.

Comment: You need to describe what you mean by "compare an array". Without that information we cannot answer the question. What we do know is you will be `O(m * the cost of comparing arrays)` since you need to make m comparisons. Assuming your "comparison" is a simple "is identical" check (which has a cost of `O(n)`) then your total cost is `O(mn)`. If your comparison was something more complex like a "contains the same elements but not necessarily in the same order" check (which has a cost of `O(n^2)`) then your cost goes up to `O(m * n^2)`.

Comment: You can reduce the complexity if you stops the comparison in i-th row of the matrix then you find that j-th element of the vector not equal to the ij element of the matrix. In worst case it will be ofcourse O(mn) but in some cases faster.

Comment: The comparison is to check if they're identical.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The comparison of two vectors can bail out early if the elements at any certain index differ. So unless you have very unevenly distributed data, a single vector comparison should be `O(1)` if the vectors are different and `O(m)` if they're equal. Thus, the overall time complexity will be `O(n + m)` if there's a match and `O(n)` if there's none. This is on average, of course, worst case will be O(mn).